# Dell R710 RAM upgrade

Tags: memory

I'm upgrading the RAM in my Dell PowerEdge R710, and I think I have a solid enough understanding of ranking and how that should effect my purchase.  Using the guide below -

http://www.dell.com/downloads/emea/products/pedge/en/installing_upgrading_ddr3_memory_11g.pdf

- could someone give me a sanity check?

It looks like there is no way to fill the server with dual ranked DIMMs.  So I couldn't buy a bunch of 4GB dual ranked DIMMS for this server, because I would hit the max of 8 ranks on whatever channel that is (bank A channel 1 and bank B channel 1 are the same channel, right?  so - 2 x 6 = 12, which is greater than the 8 max).

Also, can anyone give me a valid scenario where someone would want to buy a 16GB quad ranked DIMM?  I'm confused as to why those would even be sold... unless it's for single CPU configurations, where only one bank would be used and you'd have some ranks to burn through?

Any additional detail to aid in my understanding would be appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: The Dell support will help you. Or better: the sales department helps you out. That's their job and they should guarantee that everything they tell you is going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by following my best understanding and limiting the number of ranks being used.  I had no problem with the RAM I purchased, after changing how it was laid out on the motherboard a few times.